# Batch Script: For Loop with Two commands

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, search

I have been working on a batch script to loop through a folder and produce a list of the files sorted by when they were last modified. Right now it works as expected, but it does not search through sub-folders, below is my code:

```
echo Last executed on %date% at %time% > report.csv
echo. >> report.csv
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4,* SKIP=4" %%a IN ('DIR /O-D /TW') DO (
    IF exist %%e (
        IF NOT %%e==.. (
            IF NOT %%e==. (
                echo %%e >> report.csv
                echo %%a %%b >> report.csv
)
)
)
)
:Start
   CScript modifyexcelGood.vbs
:End
goto :eof
```

Ignore those if statements, they are just there to prevent incorrect filenames I was getting. I know the /R command is for searching through subfolders, but it appears I cannot use both /R and /F, or perhaps I am wrong? I feel like there is a simple solution but I have not been able to find it.

Thanks

**EDIT**
To clarify, the batch file sorts all the files in a directory by date modified and throws the file name and date of each file found in an excel sheet(In sorted order). It then starts a VB script that edits the sheet to make it look nice. The Vbs and bat scripts must be together but they are meant to be used in any directory. They are meant to help clean out large directories that have old files sitting around. (It will eventually delete the old files too once I know this works 100%.)

I can put these in any directory and it works fine, I just need it to hit the files in any subfolders as well.

So how can I edit my code to make it check if %%e is a directory and if so run the loop on that directory as well?

Thanks

Comment: Type `dir /?` at a command prompt, and look at the available switches - does `/S` not do what you want without needing to add another loop?

Comment: `dir /s /o-d` will sort per subdirectory. I guess, OP wants all that files sorted independend of their directory. `dir` can't do that.

Comment: @Stephan: It's unclear what the OP wants at all, since nothing was explained. Note the ? at the end of my previous comment.

Comment: @Mofi edited with clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid your request is not clear. However, the line below list the files in current folder and all subfolders beneath, one line per file, and sort *all* files by last modified date, newer files first.

```
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /T:W /S /B') do echo %%~Ta %%a) | sort /R > report.csv
```

If you have any doubt about `dir` command switches (like `/B`), type `dir /?`.

Comment: this doesn't sort by date - unless your date-format is `YYYY-MM-DD'

Answer (score 0):

to really sort the files by date, you can temporarily modify the short date format to `yyyy.MM.dd`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM get current short date format:
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate') do set orig-format=%%b
REM set short format to yyyy.MM.dd:
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d "yyyy.MM.dd" /f >nul

(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /T:W /S /B') do @echo %%~Ta %%a)|sort /r >report.csv    

REM set short date format back to original settings:
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d "%orig-format%" /f >nul
```

I stole the line from Aacini with the following changes:
- added `/a-d` to `dir` to exclude folders
- added `@` in front of `echo` which removes a lot of empty lines in the resulting file.
and put the neccessary changes for the date format around it.