# Windows 'dir' command: sort files by date when '/s' is specified

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-console

**Goal:** I want to copy the latest file with a certain extension from a "source directory" to a "destination directory" using a batch file. The latest file may be under several sub-directories within the source directory.

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97371/7355697) is exactly what I want, however it does not seem to sort when the `/s` option is specified (as [this comment would suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97371/how-do-i-write-a-windows-batch-script-to-copy-the-newest-file-from-a-directory#comment8209811_978259)):

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "K:\path\tp\source\dir\*.ext" /B /S /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
copy "%NewestFile%" "C:\path\to\destination\dir"
```

You can test `DIR "K:\path\tp\source\dir\*.ext" /B /S /O:D` by itself to see that it does not sort.

**What I've Tried:** This command by itself does work: `DIR "K:\path\tp\source\dir\*.ext" /S /B | sort` but I can't figure out how to use it in a for loop (batch file exits before I can determine the error - even with a `pause` at the end).

Any ideas?

See: [dir docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir)

Comment: Why are you using `|` as a delimiter? Windows file names cannot contain them so you should be able to use `"Delims="`.

Comment: @Compo I got it from the linked answer. Changing it to `"delims="` or `"tokens=*"` does not change the result.

Comment: The `dir` command will sort the files in each directory by the date.  It will not sort all the files in date order.  To do that you would need to output the file date as YYYYMMDD with the file name and sort the file.

Comment: @Squashman: [there is a way to do that in pure batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621769/2152082). (Although messing with the registry wouldn't be my first choice...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call out to `Powershell` from you batch file if you want to.  This code can be shortened on newer versions of `Powershell`.

```
for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('powershell "gci -rec | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Select-Object fullname"') do set NewestFile=%%G
```

Full answer:

```
cd /d "K:\path\to\source\dir"
for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('powershell "gci -rec *.ext | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Select-Object fullname"') do set NewestFile=%%G
copy "%NewestFile%" "C:\path\to\dest\dir"
```

Comment: I edited your answer to include the full solution I ended up with - thanks!

Comment: @alexleen, you may need to be very careful with this solution, I have a feeling that the returned filename may very easily become truncated and the file subsequently not copied

Comment: To mitigate some of the long file path errors you could use the PUSHD command with your source directory. ROBOCOPY is the only program I know of that does not have issues with long file paths. ROBOCOPY will not help with finding the newest file without a lot if manipulation whether that be a batch file or Powershell.

Comment: The paths don't need to be too long @Squashman, the potential issue isn't with the length as such but with the fixed column output you're returning which gets truncated.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=K:\path\tp\source\dir"
    set "mask=*.ext"

    for %%r in ("%root%\.") do for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%%~fr" "%%~fr" "%mask%" /njh /njs /nc /ns /ts /s /ndl /nocopy /is /r:0 /w:0 /l
        ^| sort /r 
        ^| cmd /v /e /c"(set /p .=&echo(!.!)"
    ') do set "lastFile=%%b"

    echo Last file : "%lastFile%"
```

This code uses `robocopy` to generate the list of files with a timestamp prefix (the switches just request no job header, no job summary, no file class, no file size, timestamp, recursive, no directory list, no directory information copy, include same files, no retry, no wait, don't copy only generate list).

This timestamp prefixed list (UTF `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` last file write) is then sorted in reverse order to get the last file in the first line. This line is retrieved with a separate `cmd` instance (this avoids a time problem with a `for /f` reading long lists of data) so the `for /f` only reads one line.

As the `robocopy` lines contain the date, time and file name, to retrieve this last field, we request the `for /f` to retrieve two tokens: one containing the hour (will be stored in `%%a`) and the remaining text until the end of the line (stored in `%%b`)

The additional `for %%r` is included just to prevent a usual problem using `robocopy`. As we are quoting paths to prevent problems with spaces, we need to ensure the paths do not end with a backslash that will escape the path's closing quote and make the command fail.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be working fine. I believe you problem lies within the `"delims=|"`statement from your original function. By using a `"delims="` all it would be doing is cutting off the first `|` from the loops output. Being that `|` would not be in a normal windows file path, it's completely not needed. Try just throwing an `"tokens=*"` in the statement instead.

I also recommend using `Set "String="` Instead of the traditional `Set String=` as spaces can be a problem in many cases. I updated that in the function.

**Batch Script:**

```
@ECHO OFF

Rem | Configuration
Set "MainDirectory=C:\Folder1"
Set "FileExtension=*.txt"
Set "CopyDestination=C:\Folder2"

Rem | Search for the newest file in a directory/sub-directory
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('DIR "%MainDirectory%\%FileExtension%" /B /S /O:D') do (SET "NewestFile=%%A")

Rem | Copy file to a destination
copy "%NewestFile%" "%CopyDestination%"

goto :EOF
```

Comment: This produces the same result. I believe the issue has to do with the `dir` command and not the for loop as you can run `DIR "%MainDirectory%\%FileExtension%" /B /S /O:D` by itself and observe incorrect sorting (or none at all).

Comment: @alexleen Works fine for me over multiple OS's. I suggest looking into powershell.