# Find most recent file of a wildcard list in batch file script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Given a directory tree like:

```
parent
   dir-v0.1.0
      subdir
   dir-v0.2.0
      subdir
   dir-v0.3.0  # lacks subdir
```

I need a Windows batch sequence (for Win7+) that works like this Unix Bash code:

```
   found=$(ls -dt ../dir-v0.*.0/subdir | head -1)
   if [ "$found" ]; then
      ...
   fi
```

A Powershell subcommand is an option. (Sadly powershell scripts don't launch on double-click.)

Command-shell wildcards can only appear in the last path element, so this doesn't work:

```
   dir /o:d ..\dir-v0.*.0\subdir
```

EDIT: This works, using powershell:

```
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set findSub=get-item ..\dir-v0.*.0\subdir ^| ^
               sort -property LastWriteTime ^| ^
               select -last 1 -expandproperty FullName
   set findSub=powershell -noprofile -command "!findSub!"
   for /f "delims=" %%V in ('!findSub!') do set found=%%V
   if defined found (...)
```

Comment: There is no obvious solution in batch. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621769/2152082) involves temporarily modifying the registry, so you should be sure to know what you do.

Comment: `ls -dt ..\*\subdir` finds directories containing `subdir` and sorts them by last-modified datetime of `subdir`. I only need directories matching regex `dir-v0\.[1-9][0-9]*\.0`. I edited post to include a powershell solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

The batch file below can be used to get the full qualified name of the version directory in parent directory of the batch file directory containing a subdirectory `subdir` with the second number being the greatest number of all version directories with a subdirectory `subdir` as long as the second number in version string has never one or more leading zeros.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "PreviousVersion=-1"
set "VersionDirectory="

for /D %%I in ("%~dp0..\dir-v0.*.0") do if exist "%%I\subdir\" (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%J in ("%%~nxI") do (
        set "CurrentVersion=%%J"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if !CurrentVersion! GTR !PreviousVersion! (
            endlocal
            set "VersionDirectory=%%I"
            set "PreviousVersion=%%J"
        ) else endlocal
    )
)

if defined VersionDirectory (
    echo Directory with greatest version number containing subdir is:
    echo(
    echo "%VersionDirectory%"
) else (
    echo Could not find any version directory with subdir.
)

echo(
pause
endlocal
```

The batch file can be faster if it is guaranteed that the path to the version directories never contains one or more exclamation marks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PreviousVersion=-1"
set "VersionDirectory="

for /D %%I in ("%~dp0..\dir-v0.*.0") do if exist "%%I\subdir\" (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%J in ("%%~nxI") do (
        if %%J GTR !PreviousVersion! (
            set "VersionDirectory=%%I"
            set "PreviousVersion=%%J"
        )
    )
)

if defined VersionDirectory (
    echo Directory with greatest version number containing subdir is:
    echo(
    echo !VersionDirectory!
) else (
    echo Could not find any version directory with subdir.
)

echo(
pause
endlocal
```

[Delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled for the entire batch file in this case.

**Note:** Command **FOR** with option `/D` ignores directories with hidden attribute set.

Remove `%~dp0` and modify `set "VersionDirectory=%%I"` to `set "VersionDirectory=%%~fI"` if the used batch file should run on parent directory of current directory independent on storage location of the batch file.

The condition `if exist "%%I\subdir\"` can be removed if it should not matter if the version directory contains already the subdirectory `subdir` or not.

The following code can be used to get the file name without path of newest file in subdirectory `subdir` of the version directory with greatest version number:

```
set "NewestFile="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%K in ('dir "%VersionDirectory%" /A-D /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do set "NewestFile=%%K" & goto HaveNewestFile

:HaveNewestFile
if not defined NewestFile (
    echo Failed to find a file in directory: "%VersionDirectory%"
) else (
    echo Newest file in "%VersionDirectory%" is: "%NewestFile%"
)
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file directory path always ending with a backslash.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`