# Batch file to find current date (day-month) and showing result accordingly

Tags: date, batch-file, find

I'm creating a batch file that copies specific files depending on the current weekday. That works fine!

However, I'd like to add another feature which would check which month and date it currently is and print a specific date message (current birthdays for example) while it performs copying. How could I achieve this? I don't mind adding lines for every day of the year in a way I've done for different weekdays.

````
Set "_=mon tues wed thurs fri sat sun" 
For /f %%# In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek^|Findstr [0-6]') Do ( 
    Set DOW=%%#)
echo %DOW% >NUL
IF %DOW%==0 (goto sunday)
IF %DOW%==1 (goto monday)
IF %DOW%==2 (goto tuesday)
IF %DOW%==3 (goto wednesday)
IF %DOW%==4 (goto thursday)
IF %DOW%==5 (goto friday)
IF %DOW%==6 (goto saturday)
goto finish
:monday
    echo Copying files for monday
    copy test.file testmonday.file /b/v/y >NUL
    goto finish
:tuesday
    echo Copying files for tuesday
    copy test.file testtuesday.file /b/v/y >NUL
    goto finish
:wednesday
    echo Copying files for wednesday
    copy test.file testwednesday.file /b/v/y >NUL
    goto finish
:thursday
    echo Copying files for thursday
    copy test.file testthursday.file /b/v/y >NUL
    goto finish
:friday
    echo Copying files for friday
    copy test.file testfriday.file /b/v/y >NUL
    goto finish
:saturday
    echo Copying files for saturday
    copy test.file testsaturday.file /b/v/y >NUL
    goto finish
:sunday
    echo Copying files for sunday
    copy test.file testsunday.file /b/v/y >NUL
    goto finish
:finish
    echo Files copied succesfully!
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating code is hard to maintain. Better use a loop and re-use the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
Set "Days=Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday" 
For /f %%# In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek^|Findstr [0-6]') Do Set /a DOW=%%#+1
for /f "tokens=%DOW%" %%# in ("%Days%") do set "WeekDay=%%#"
echo copying files for %WeekDay%
ECHO copy /b/v/y "test.file" "test%WeekDay%.file" 

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%# in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /value') do set "dt=%%#"
set "DateMonth=%dt:~4,2%
set "DateDay=%dt:~6,2%"
echo Today is %WeekDay%, %DateDay%.%DateMonth%. Let me remind you:
findstr /lc:"%dateDay%.%DateMonth%." "Birthdays.txt"
```

Output:

```
copying files for Thursday
copy /b/v/y "test.file" "testThursday.file"
Today is Thursday, 21.01. Let me remind you:
21.01.2021 I answered a question on SO
```

(NOTE: I disarmed the `copy` command by just echoing it. Remove the `ECHO` to enable it)

I'm sure, you are able to adapt the "Day.Month" string to your needs.

Comment: Another option could be `for /f "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=/" %%a in ('date /t') do (set "dayn=%%a" & set "monthn=%%b" & set "yearn=%%c") echo:& echo Today is the !dayn!-!monthn!-!yearn!.`

Comment: @MicEsp: I very much dislike to process `%date%`, as it's highly configurable and dependent on local settings. For example, my `%date%` shows `21.01.2021`. Your suggestion would result in `dayn=21.01.2021` and not even setting the other two variables.

Comment: honestly did not know that, nice to know it now. To bypass this, could you kind of set "a set" of delimiters, i.e. `"tokens=1,2,3,* delims=/.,-:"` so that you have a wider range of them?
Another way could be that of extracting actual delimiter of `date` by finding the first non-numeric character at first.

Comment: @MicEsp What's with `Donnerstag, DD.MM.YYYY` vs. `MM/DD/YY`? Similar with `%time%`: some use AM/PM format, others use 24h format Some use a dot, others uses a comma to separate the milliseconds. I'm using an English Windows at work and a German Windows at home, so I prefer a solution that will work on *every* Windows-box.

Comment: So, @stephan, the question is straightforward: is there a way to change the way `date` or `time` output info (i.e. change format)? In other words, is it know from where they do extract the info (it should be somewhere)?

Comment: yes, it's in the registry. I used it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621769/2152082)

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, much obliged! Works like a charm and is so much simpler than my initial suggestion.