# How to copy newest 100 files from thousands of subfolders to another folder?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, copy, subdirectory

I have to copy the first 100 files with a specific file extension to another folder daily.

The source folder looks like this:

```
sourcefolder\ParentFolderA
├───folder1
│   └──────file_a.dat
├───folder2
│   └──────file_b.dat
└───folder3
    └──────file_c.dat
```

I need to grab the newest 100 `.dat` files – there is only one `.dat` file in each folder UNDER the `ParentFolderA` – and copy them to a new folder.

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "index = 0"
set /a "count = 99"
set "source=sourcefolder\ParentFolderA\"
set "destination=destinationfolder\somerandomFoldername"

:whileloop
if %index% leq %count% (
     echo %index%
     for /R "%source%" %%f in (*.dat) do copy %%f "%destination%"
     set /a "index = index + 1"
     goto :whileloop
)
endlocal

timeout 10
```

Some of it will be taken out as I just have it in there to help me while I am writing it. The end behavior is to get those 100 newest `.dat` files. Currently this is grabbing **ALL** the .dat files in every subfolder, but it never terminates because it doesn´t have a chance to get to the incrementing portion of code. (There are thousands of folders it would have to go through before it got to that step).

Can someone give me some tips or an advice on where/how I can achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of all your files which is sortable by date/time. There isn't a command capable to do this recursive in `cmd`. But it's possible with a trick, I used [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621769/2152082): Temporarily set the date format to a sortable format, get the list and set it back to the original format:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a "count=100"
set "source=sourcefolder\ParentFolderA\"
set "destination=destinationfolder\somerandomFoldername"

REM get current short date format:
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate') do set orig-format=%%b
REM set short format to yyyy.MM.dd:
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d "yyyy.MM.dd" /f >nul

REM get a recursive listing with format "YYYY.MM.DD hh:mm <full qualified file name>":
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /T:W /S /B "%source%\*"') do @echo %%~Ta "%%a")|sort /r>report.csv 

REM set short date format back to original settings:
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d "%orig-format%" /f >nul

REM copy the first %count% files:
set n=0
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in (report.csv) do (
  set /a n+=1
  if !n! gtr %count% goto :done
  ECHO copy %%b "%destination%\" 
)
:done
echo done.
```

Adapt `/T:W` to your needs.

Note: I "disarmed" the `copy` command for security reasons. When it works as you want it to, just remove the `ECHO`.

(sorry to quote the filename within the `for` loop. I know it's bad habit, but it
is necessary because `sort` manages to add a space to the end of each line.)

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"


:: I used 20 files for my test
SET /a maxfiles=20

:: I chose to process all the .T* files
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%b IN (*.t*) DO COPY "%%b" "%destdir%\" >NUL
FOR /f "skip=%maxfiles%delims=" %%b IN ('DIR /b /a-d /o-d "%destdir%\*.t*" ') DO ECHO DEL "%destdir%\%%b"
GOTO :EOF
```

Since you seem to have no objections to building a complete copy of your target files, all that is needed is to delete all of the files from a directory listing in reverse-date order, skipping the required number of retentions.

The `echo del`  is present for verification, to make sure the directory is correct. Change `echo del` to `del` to execute the deletions.

Comment: this does great however i cant get it to terminate. @Magoo

Comment: What does it do once the required files have been deleted? Terminates on my test setup...

Comment: it continues to copy files, it doesnt stop at the maxfiles quantity