# Batch Scripting - Identifying oldest and newest file in a folder/directory

Tags: batch-file, duplicates

So im trying to make a script where the batch file searches a certain directory, it's folders and sub-folders, for duplicated files. It then should also identify the oldest file(that is most probably the original) and the newest file(that is probably the one where the user is working on currently) and also  ask the user if it wants to delete each file from all the ones it identified (even the oldest and newest but when it comes up for them to be deleted it should identify them as oldest and newest)
Im new to this kind of scripting so forgive me for stupid mistakes i made.
In this case i made a "Giorgio" Word document and placed it in some sub-folders, in one i altered what was written as well and dire

Here is the part im trying to work on, that is about identifying the oldest and newest file. I believe im trying to do something i'm not allowed, im using these commands wrong

```
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        """dir /a-d /b /tw /od "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1" /Giorgio.docx"
   ) do set %file%=="oldest"   
   echo %oldest%

   for /f "delims=" %%a in (
       """dir /a-d /b /tw /o-d "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1 /*Giorgio.docx"" 
   ) do set %file%=="newest"
   echo %newest%
```

This is my whole program if you guys are curious
(sorry if some sentences aren't well written, i've translated everything from portuguese to english in the last 3 minutes)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "source_folder=C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1\Giorgio.docx"

echo Welcome to this Practice/Test Program
echo This program has the obective of finding duplicated files. 
pause
echo The user will have the chance to eliminate these files if he wishes
echo There will be the identification of the oldest and the newest file
pause

echo Let us start...
pause

          
:aPrompt
cls
echo ========================================
echo What do you wish to do?
echo 1.Show only the duplicated files. (Clique '1')
echo 2.Show the duplicated files and eliminate them.  (Clique '2')
echo 3.Exit the program (Clique '3')



choice /n /c:123 /M "Escolha uma opcao "%1
goto Alfa-%errorlevel%


:Alfa-1 A1

   
   echo Showing the files being analysed

   forfiles /P "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1" /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @file"

   echo Showing the paths of the files being analysed
   
   forfiles /P "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1"  /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @relpath@fname"

   pause
   echo ===============================================================================
            
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        """dir /a-d /b /tw /od "C:\Users\11506018\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1" /Giorgio.docx"
   ) do set %file%=="oldest"   
   echo %oldest%
   
   

  
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (
       """dir /a-d /b /tw /o-d "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1 /*Giorgio.docx"" 
   ) do set %file%=="newest"
   echo %newest%
  echo=======================
  echo=======================
  echo=======================
  pause
     
   :bPrompt
   echo Here are the duplicated files
   echo Do you wish to leave or go back? (Type '1' to end the program, '2' to return to the previous menu)
   
  
   
   choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
   goto Bravo-%errorlevel%
   :Bravo-1 B
      echo The program will now end
      pause
      exit
   
   :Bravo-2 B
      echo You chose to go back
      pause
      goto :aPrompt

:Alfa-2 A2

   echo You chose to show and eliminate the duplicated files
   pause
   echo Showing the files paths
   forfiles /P "C:\Users\11506018\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1"  /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @relpath@fname" 
   
   echo Files identyfied by the the program (it serves the purpose of confirming if they are the right files)
   
   forfiles /P "C:\Users\11506018\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1" /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @file"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        """dir /a-d /b /tw /od "C:\Users\11506018\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1" /Giorgio.docx"
   ) do set %file%=="oldest"   
   echo %oldest%
   
   

  
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (
       """dir /a-d /b /tw /o-d "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1 /*Giorgio.docx"" 
   ) do set %file%=="newest"
   echo %newest%
   
   echo You sure you want to delete the files? (Type '1' to eliminate them, '2' to not eliminate)
   
   :cPrompt
   choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
   goto Charlie-%errorlevel%
   :Charlie-1 C1
   
       echo You chose to delete the files
       
       
       echo The files will be deleted according to your decision
       echo For each file it will be asked if you wish to delete it
       pause
       del /p /s "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1"\*Giorgio.docx 
       echo The files have been deleted at your choice
       pause
       :dPrompt
       echo Do you wish to exit the program or go back? (Type '1' to end the program, type '2' to go back to the main menu)
       
       choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
       goto Delta-%errorlevel%
       :Delta-1 D1
       
       
           echo You chose to leave. The program will shut down
           pause
           exit
       
       :Delta-2 D2
      
       
           echo You chose to go back to the main menu
           pause
           goto :aPrompt
   
   :Charlie-2 C2
   
       :ePrompt
       echo You chose not to delete the files.
       echo Do you wish to go back to the main menu or to leave? (Type '1' to go back to the main menu, '2' to leave the program)
       
       
       choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
       goto Evo-%errorlevel%
       :Evo-1 E1
       
           echo You chose to go back to the main menu
           pause
           goto :aPrompt
       
       :Evo-2 E2
          echo You chose to exit the program. The program will shut down now
          pause
          exit
       
       
:Alfa-3 A3

    echo The program will shut down then
    pause
    exit
```

I haven't found a script anywhere like this. If i manage to get it to work i'll share it here in Stack Overflow so that in the future, people that need something similar can have more content to work with

Comment: wrong `for` syntax: `for /f ... in ('command') do ...` (surrounding single quotes for the command, expained in `for /?`)

Comment: `set` syntax is also wrong. See `set /?`

Comment: oh - and how many files with the exact same name do you expect in a single folder?

Comment: Well, so far i've made 1 "Giorgio.docx" for each folder. Can be spread around a lot of sub-folders . I may make it so even the same doc copied in the same folder to be identified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides some severe syntax errors (you can get help with each command with the `/?` switch, for example `set /?`, `for /?`).
Besides those, you can do it in just one loop:

```
set "oldest=NONE"
set "newest=NONE"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /tw /od "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1\*Giorgio.docx"') do (
  if not defined oldest set "oldest=%%a"
  set "newest=%%a"
)
echo oldest: %oldest%
echo newest: %newest%
```

Note: There can be only one file with the same name in a folder, so searching for the newest/oldest file in a folder does only make sense with a wildcard. I guessed here, so you certainly want to check/change `*Giorgio.docx`

Comment: Yes, im only having 1 file for each folder and sub-folder where this program is running

Comment: " 'fset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "
Also, i can i echo the paths of the oldest and newest file?

Comment: There is no `fset` in my code. Full path is `%%~fa` instead of `%%a`. `dir` can't sort over subfolders ([there is a trick to do it anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621769/2152082))

Comment: sorry, i wrote it wrong, had  an "f" behind "set" by mistake.
Im going to check out your answer better. Thank you :)